# MySQL Сведение разных таблиц в одну

Tags: mysql, select, join, union

Доходы фитнесс-клуба состоят из покупок абонементов и складываются в таблицу:

```
payments:
id | abonementID | cost | data
1  | 2357        | 1200 | 2019-10-14 13:30:40
2  | 4425        | 2300 | 2019-10-14 14:55:32
3  | 9834        | 1150 | 2019-10-14 16:01:54
```

Расходы состоят из выплат зарплаты тренерам

```
payouts:
id | trainerID | salary | data
1  | 23        | 15200  | 2019-10-14 10:11:33
2  | 25        | 40000  | 2019-10-14 15:06:12
```

Таблицы в реальности содержат больше полей, и одинаковые в них толе поле `date`

Вот ни как не могу сообразить как мне сделать выписку по счёту. Мне нужны ВСЕ данные из обеих таблиц за определённый период отсортированные по дате. Но я не могу использовать UNION так как табилцы имеют совершенно разный формат и не понимаю как использовать JOIN ибо мне не нужно сопоставлять данные.

Вот что я хочу получить:

```
balance:
trainerID | salary | data                | abonementID | cost
23        | 15200  | 2019-10-14 10:11:33 | null        | null
null      | null   | 2019-10-14 13:30:40 | 2357        | 1200 
null      | null   | 2019-10-14 14:55:32 | 4425        | 2300 
25        | 40000  | 2019-10-14 15:06:12 | null        | null
null      | null   | 2019-10-14 16:01:54 | 9834        | 1150
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> я не могу использовать UNION так как табилцы имеют совершенно разный формат

Недостающие поля дополняются литералами (в данном случае - NULL):

```
SELECT NULL trainerID, NULL salary, data, abonementID, cost
FROM payments
UNION ALL
SELECT trainerID, salary, data, NULL, NULL
FROM payouts
ORDER BY data
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Всё утро шерстил документацию и форумы, а на такой вариант использования UNION не наткнулся. Не знал, что UNION так умеет.

Comment: @ЕвгенийНиколаевичОлейник UNION всё пофиг - лишь бы количество полей совпадало и тип значения нормально приводился к шаблонному (тому, что в первом подзапросе). А там поле, литерал или переменная - ему сиренево, у него одна задача - всё в кучу свалить.